# History of recent calls not displaying Caller's information on iOS14

Tags: ios, phone-call, callkit, ios14

The Contact application I have is already allowed to provide caller ID under the Call Blocking & Identification on the Phone. The app shows the information and identification of the user who called/ had been called on the History of Recent calls on iOS 14 below. But this feature is not working on iOS 14 and later versions.

Details when a call is incoming is displayed correctly and has no problems. It is only on the History that is not showing the Caller's information and identification.

Caller information Display
Incoming Call - O
History - X

This is only happened on the iOS 14 update. It's working properly on lower iOS versions. Anyone else seen this? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing same misbehaviour in contact app we are developing and we couldnt figured out exact reason for it to do so.Any update or clue in your situation might help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same experience...can't find out why too